# ESRI JS API - CIMSymbol with text from graphic attribute

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cartographic-information-model

The following sample shows a great use of the CIMSymbol in the ESRI JS API.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/cim-symbols/index.html

Is it possible to set the textString property on the markergraphic to an attribute of the graphic?

https://github.com/Esri/cim-spec/blob/master/docs/v2/CIMSymbols.md#cimmarkergraphic

I'd like to place a number (attribute of the graphic) in the centre of the symbol and have tried "{$feature.numfld}" but this just displays the text string, not the expresssion value.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by Anne Fritz from Esri in an email to me:

> This is not currently possible for CIMSymbol. You could add labels to
>   your FeatureLayer instead of doing it through the CIMSymbol. See this
>   example: Add labels to a FeatureLayer | ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.15
>
> There's more information available in the API Reference:
>   FeatureLayer.labelingInfo | ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.15